# Literally Canvas createshape 'Line' braking svg export

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

Createshape 'Line' is braking the svg's I'm exporting from Literally Canvas.  If I comment out the createshape 'Line' below it works - uncomment it and the svg has an error.  Anybody know what the issue might be?

```
//create
var lc = LC.init(
    document.getElementsByClassName('drawingapp')[0],
    {
        backgroundColor: 'whiteSmoke', 
        backgroundShapes: [
            LC.createShape('Rectangle', {x: 76, y: 95, width: 669, height: 337, strokeWidth: 5, strokeColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)'}), 
            LC.createShape('Line', {x1: 48, y1: 50, x2: 48, y2: 515, strokeWidth: 40, color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)', capStyle: 'round', endCapShapes: ['arrow', 'arrow']})
        ],
       imageSize: imageSize
    }
);


//export
var svgURL = lc.getSVGString(lc.getSnapshot(), {rect: imageBounds});
window.open("data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgURL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  There is an error in defineSVGRenderer('Line'):

```
return "<g> <line x1='" + x1 + "' y1='" + y1 + "' x2='" + x2 + "' y2='" + y2 + "' " + dashString + " stroke-linecap='" + shape.capStyle + "' stroke='" + shape.color + " 'stroke-width='" + shape.strokeWidth + "' /> " + capString + " </g>";
```

should be:

```
return "<g> <line x1='" + x1 + "' y1='" + y1 + "' x2='" + x2 + "' y2='" + y2 + "' " + dashString + " stroke-linecap='" + shape.capStyle + "' stroke='" + shape.color + "' stroke-width='" + shape.strokeWidth + "' /> " + capString + " </g>";
```

HINT: The single comma straight after shape.color.